# How to prove that probability density function of the sum of 2 independant variable is equal to their convolution?

Tags: random-variables, convolution, density-function

The probability density function of the sum of two independent random variables is the convolution of their individual probability density functions.

What is the simplest demonstration that proves that ?

Comment: Hint:  Write an integral expression for the _CDF_ of the sum of two independent continuous random variables with given densities. Differentiate to find the pdf of the sum

Comment: Try proving the discrete counterpart first.